# Half sphere no show when enlarge it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use a half sphere to be my sky. but the problem is when the half-sphere is go larger,

it's not showing in the scene.

[image]

How can I make it as my sky box?

[image]

Comment: Can you check your camera's far clipping value? Everything further away from the camera is not rendered ... Also.have in mind that with a default shader the backfaces (triangles from within) are not rendered either  .. invert the normals/use or configure a shader of the material for rendering backfaces ... I would rather recommend to use a proper skybox material instead of this "wasted" mesh ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go blender or other 3d software,

in blender add Solidify Modifier then set the thickness to 0.05 or more.

and you will see the half-sphere show.